# replace random number in a string with a specific number in R

Tags: r, string, replace, numbers

I have a txt file and I want to replace a random number from a string with a specific number that I have choosen. For example:

```
txt[15] = "\t<!-- number=31                                                            -->"
```

I want substitute the number after "=" with "15", but keeping all the structure and the spaces in the string. So, just changing the number. I'm trying to do it in R.

Comment: the string ends at  -->"

Comment: It is written in my post. I showed that string txt[15] is "\t<!-- number=31                                                            -->".

Comment: I imagined...but in the post I wrote in the right way...however, the string is like it is shown in the comment.

Comment: Sorry, it was too long that I didn't check the end.  I updated the solution.

Comment: Thank you akrun...Don't worry, I was imaging that it was for that reason.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `sub`

```
 sub('\\d+', '15', str1)
 #[1] "\t<!-- number=15                                                            -->"
```

To be exact

```
 sub('(?<=[=])\\d+', '15', str1, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "\t<!-- number=15                                                            -->"
```

Or

```
 sub('([^=]+=)\\d+', '\\115', str1)
 #[1] "\t<!-- number=15                                                            -->"
```

#### data

```
  str1 <- str1 <- "\t<!-- number=31                                                            -->"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sub

```
sub("=\\d+", "=15", s)
```